# PayPal Adaptive Payments - Preapproval request results in "Invalid request" error

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I can't figure out what's happening with my `Preapproval` HTTP POST request. I'm just trying to do a basic call to PayPal's [Adaptive Payments API](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPreapproval), the `Preapproval` call specifically. And the PayPal error `580001` "Invalid request" is not that helpful in itself.

Request Headers (based on my Sandbox's account credentials, which I changed to `xxx`):

```
{
  'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
  'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD': 'xxx',
  'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
  'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE': 'xxx',
  'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID': 'xx',
  'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID': 'APP-80W284485P519543T'
}
```

My request payload (HTTP POST, body encoded in JSON):

```
{
  "requireInstantFundingSource": "TRUE", 
  "returnUrl": "http://www.google.com/?paypal=ok", 
  "maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments": 1002, 
  "maxNumberOfPaymentsPerPeriod": 1, 
  "endingDate": "2014-03-14T16:49:36+0000", 
  "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage": "en_US", 
  "clientDetails.applicationId": "XXX", 
  "cancelUrl": "http://www.google.com/paypal=cancel", 
  "startingDate": "2013-09-15T16:49:36+0000", 
  "feesPayer": "PRIMARYRECEIVER", 
  "currencyCode": "SEK"
}
```

The above POST body is posted to:

```
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval
```

Response from Paypal ("prettified" for understanding):

```
{
  "responseEnvelope": {
    "ack": "Failure", 
    "timestamp": "2013-09-10T09:56:43.031-07:00", 
    "build": "6941298", 
    "correlationId": "26d55e6bfcaa0"
  }, 
  "error": [
    {
      "category": "Application", 
      "domain": "PLATFORM", 
      "severity": "Error", 
      "message": "Invalid request: {0}", 
      "subdomain": "Application", 
      "errorId": "580001"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK fixed. How?

**Fix #1**

The arguments `requestEnvelope.errorLanguage` and `clientDetails.applicationId` need to be "JSONified" into objects on their own, such as:

```
"requestEnvelope": {
    "errorLanguage": "en_US"
},
```

and

```
"clientDetails": {
    "applicationId": "APP-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
},
```

respectively.

**Fix #2**

Date formats; date format should be of the form `2014-03-15T20:14:38.007+00:00` and not `2014-03-14T20:14:38+0000` as I was passing. Note the milliseconds, and the timezone with the colon in the utc offset.

Next time an `Invalid request` comes up the parameters I'm passing will be the first thing to look at.